# How to update Gradle dependencies from command line?

Tags: java, gradle

I have following `build.gradle` file:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'

sourceCompatibility = 1.7
version = '1.0'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-core:4.1.1.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-context:4.1.1.RELEASE'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.+'
}
```

I run following command:

```
$ gradle --refresh-dependencies
```

**But it does nothing. The dependencies do not get updated and do not reflect on classpath.** The output from command is:

```
:help

Welcome to Gradle 2.1.

To run a build, run gradle <task> ...

To see a list of available tasks, run gradle tasks

To see a list of command-line options, run gradle --help

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 5.999 secs
```

Doing this via Eclipse gradle plugin is working though.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

```
gradle --refresh-dependencies <task>
```

Answer (score 38):

I am using Gradle 2.9 and I use this for force refresh:

```
gradle build --refresh-dependencies
```

Answer (score 7):

You should  first clean with `gradle clean` and then `gradle eclipse` finally go to project in eclipse and refresh the project, it works for my.

Comment: Upvoted because this is the way to do it it in VS Code. Add the dependency in your build.gradle then `gradle build --refresh-dependencies`, then `gradle clean` and finally `gradle eclipse` to see the updated jars. Use the Java Dependency Explorer extension to confirm; it's quite handy!

Comment: build --refresh-dependencies in eclipse run configurations gives the error "Unknown command line arguments"

Answer (score 4):

for gradle refresh to perform , run the below command via command prompt

```bash
gradle --refresh-dependencies clean build
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to fetch dependencies without running build (or all the tasks), you could use `dependency-verification`:

```
gradle --write-verification-metadata sha256 help
```

Note that as explained [here](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/force-resolving-and-downloading-all-dependencies/35942/2):

> it’s an approximation of what dependencies could be downloaded during
> a build. In particular, if a task uses what we call a “detached
> configuration” (a dynamic dependency graph at execution time), then
> those dependencies will not be downloaded, because they are opaque to
> Gradle.

Comment: This created some file in workspace & fcked up my gradle build, can't build anymore

Answer (score -1):

If you have multiple projects then and want to execute only on one project the clean-eclipse (without quotation marks)

```
gradle 'project name':clean 'project name':eclipse --refresh-dependencies
```

after you just refresh the project in your IDE.